# Recommended subset of files to version control when generating an ExtJs app with sencha-cmd

Tags: svn, extjs, sencha-cmd

After generating a project skeleton with sencha cmd 5.0, what is the recommend subset of files to commit to version control?

Also, what is the correct procedure for other developers to follow when checking-out the project from SVN? Will they have to run sencha generate commands along with checking files out, or is it standard procedure to check-in enough data that other developers do not need to have sencha cmd or run sencha cmd commands?

Comment: For **any** environment the recommended minimal subset of files is the ones that cannot be regenerated.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you should only store in Subversion the files that cannot be generated from other items that are already versioned.

For example, with a Java program, you would only version the source code and build scripts; class or JAR files would not be versioned because they are compiled artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

I used to version all custom source code in /app and the /.sencha project directory (even if these XML files not change too much, still good to keep track of changes, because they define the ant build process). /bootstrap.js and /bootstrap.json is also important to track (it changes upon "sencha app refresh") - it's the load-queue for the framework's microloader (varies a bit from v4 to v5)... while one can ordinary skip the whole /ext directory - also /sass and /overrides, if not used.